# visual studio publish build generated files

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, build

During the build process, some files are generated by the system (concatenated, minified and versionned assets).

As these files are created on the fly, they're not added to the project, so when I publish, visual studio don't copy them.

Is there a way to tell VS to copy all files inside a folder?

Comment: you should go to publish tab on project properties page - then go to application files list - and tell VS to include necessary files into publishing

Comment: or maybe you can find answer in this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364644/visual-studio-2010-publish-minified-javascript-files-instead-of-the-original-on?rq=1

Comment: @sqladmin I can't find the option ("application file list" or similar wording) you talk about (I'm on VS 2010).

Comment: i got russian VS2010 so maybe i gave you wrong translation )) - it is first button in the group of four buttons at right side of the 'publish' tab in project properties

Comment: if project is web application - properties page is different from page for winforms application project - just look for option 'include all files from project folder' or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been able to resolve the issue by manually editing the `.csproj` file and adding those lines:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
    CustomCollectFiles;
    $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
  </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
    CustomCollectFiles;
    $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
  </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="CustomCollectFiles">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_CustomFiles Include="public\form\dist\*.js" />
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_CustomFiles.Identity)">
        <DestinationRelativePath>public\form\dist\%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
      </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: but where do i put it? there are more than one in my project... fml